# How are negative errorbar bounds transformed, when log axis scaling is applied before constructing a Seaborn lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting some lines with Seaborn:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# dfs: dict[str, DataFrame]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for label, df in dfs.items():
    sns.lineplot(
        data=df,
        x="Iteration",
        y="Loss",
        errorbar="sd",
        label=label,
        ax=ax,
    )

ax.set(xscale='log', yscale='log')
```

The result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTsMw.png).

Note the clipped negative values in the lower error band of the "effector_final_velocity" curve, since the standard deviation of the loss is larger than its mean, for those iterations.

However, if `ax.set(xscale='log', yscale='log')` is called *before* the looped calls to `sns.lineplot`, the result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EURJq.png)

I'm not sure where the unclipped values are arising.

Looking at the source of `seaborn.relational`: at the end of `lineplot`, the `plot` method of a `_LinePlotter` instance is called. It plots the error bands by passing the already-computed standard deviation bounds to `ax.fill_between`.

Inspecting the values of these bounds right before they are passed to `ax.fill_between`, the negative values (which would be clipped) are still present. Thus I had assumed that the "unclipping" behaviour must be something matplotlib is doing during the call to `ax.fill_between`, since `_LinePlotter.plot` appears to do no other relevant post-transformations of any data before it returns, and `lineplot` returns immediately.

However, consider a small example that calls `fill_between` where some of the lower bounds are negative:

```py
import numpy as np 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(5, 5))

np.random.seed(5678)

ax.fill_between(
    np.arange(10), 
    np.random.random((10,)) - 0.2,
    np.random.random((10,)) + 0.75,
)

ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Then it makes no difference if `ax.set_yscale('log')` is called before `ax.fill_between`; in both cases the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctRUi.png).

I've spent some time searching for answers about this in the Seaborn and matplotlib documentation, and looked for answers on SA and elsewhere, but I haven't found any information about what is going on here.

Comment: Isn't `errorbar="sd"` a confusing choice for data that is log scaled? Maybe consider `errorbar="ci"`?